# Creating report in Microsoft Access

Tags: outlook, report

I am working for a hospital and must create a form which MDs can use to submit accounts of child abuse. I must use **Microsoft Access.**

I have created the form itself, but I must now create a way which information can be harvested from the form. For example, if the doctor inputs the age, where can I store this?
I know access works through fields, but not how to create them. Is it useful here to use excel?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Condolences on having to use Access :-) Been there, done that.

Access stores the data in "tables". A "form" is just a front end for entering or displaying table data. When a doctor enters the age, that field in the form needs to be linked to a column in the underlying table.

When you want to create a "report", you will first need to create a "query" that selects and sorts the data from one or more "tables". You can see the query results in a spreadsheet format while you are designing the query. Then you can create a "report" which is a formatted layout for the query results.

I would recommend a book like [Access 2010: The Missing Manual](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449382371) to help you get up to speed on Access quicker.

Comment: I keep receieving the error:

"Cannot repeat table name in FROM clause".

On microsoft's site, it says:

"You cannot list the table name more than once. Remove the extra occurrences of the table name or use an alias. If you are trying to join a table to itself, use an alias to change the second reference to the table."

My issue is that I cannot find the second use of my table name. It is the name of one of my 3 tables, but does not show up elsewhere in the program. How do I find this "duplicate" and fix it?